# iOS - Google Analytics delegate methods not being called and page views not tracking

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I'm trying to create a sample application for iOS which can use Google Analytics. I've created a free account on Google Analytics, got the Tracking ID and used it in Google's sample "BasicExample" (just for the purpose of testing).

I ran the application (in both simulator and device) and there was no error, however, my Google Analytics account does not register any activity (even after two days), so I tried turning debug on and implementing the GANTrackerDelegate methods.

When the tracker is dispatched, the delegate methods are not called and something more or less like this is logged in the console:

```
2012-08-17 09:25:53.835 BasicExample[402:707] dispatch called
2012-08-17 09:25:53.839 BasicExample[402:707] dispatching 5 hits
2012-08-17 09:25:53.853 BasicExample[402:707] GET /__utm.gif?utmwv=4.8mi&utmn=20613118&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=320x480&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=pt-br&utmp=%2FSUPAPAGE&utmac=UA-34104824-1&utmcc=__utma%3D1.1516748783.1345205912.1345205912.1345205912.1%3B&utmht=1345205912658&utmqt=441194 HTTP/1.1

Host: www.google-analytics.com

User-Agent: GoogleAnalytics/1.4 (iPod touch; U; CPU iPhone OS 5.0.1 like Mac OS X; pt-br)
```

After this, everytime the tracker is dispatched again, the message "...dispatcher was busy" is logged in the console. And my Google Analytics account is not updated.

Here's my AppDelegate code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[GANTracker sharedTracker] setDebug:YES];
    [[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID:@"UA-XXXXXXXX-1" dispatchPeriod:5 delegate:self];

    NSError* error = nil;

    if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackPageview:@"/app_entry_point" withError:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"error in trackPageview");
    }

    [window_ makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[GANTracker sharedTracker] stopTracker];
    [window_ release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)hitDispatched:(NSString *)hitString
{
    NSLog(@"foo");
}

- (void)trackerDispatchDidComplete:(GANTracker *)tracker eventsDispatched:(NSUInteger)hitsDispatched eventsFailedDispatch:(NSUInteger)hitsFailedDispatch
{
    NSLog(@"bar");
}
```

There's a proxy on my local network.

Does someone knows why the delegate methods never get called and that thing is logged in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when you call the dispatch method just after tracking something ? You can do it with this :

```
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] dispatch]; // Manual dispatch
```

This method can be useful only if you don't make 2 calls at close interval. Else it will no longer dispatch ("...dispatcher was busy" problem).

If you want to clear the hits stack (you will have to do it if you want Google analytics to work again), you have to delete the app from the simulator